# Convention on $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ functions which can take vectors as input; are they 2 x 1 or 1 x 2 vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Let $S: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} $, be a function where $x, y \mapsto x + y$, let $M_{2X2}$ be some matrix $M: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, and $\vec v = (x, y)$ some vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

First, supposing I just defined $\vec v$ ambiguously like I just did, is there a convention on whether it is a 2x1 or a 1x2 vector? So that if I want the matrix-vector product $M\vec v$ to be used as an input in $S$, rigorously speaking, does the reader expect me to transpose $\vec v$, i.e., $S(M(\vec v^T))$?

Secondly, if I define $S$ s.t. $x, y \mapsto x + y$, is there any convention on whether $S$ takes by default 2 by 1 vectors or 1 by 2 vectors?

Thank you.

Comment: The symbols "$x,y\mapsto x+y$" do not describe a function $S:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: ah my bad, you're right, I meant $\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Vectors are typically presented as column vectors so $2 \times 1$ and if you write it as a row vector transpose is appropriate.

Comment: Short answer. The only time you must have a column vector is when you multiply (on the left) by a matrix to describe a linear transformation. If you're just talking about functions of two variables, or linear transformations ( not their matrices), then a vector is just a tuple, not a matrix with just one row or one column.

Comment: @EthanBolker thank you, this has solved a lot of confusion